# django template form target with dynamic data

Tags: html, django, forms, django-templates

i'm new at django template. i have a search field in header and i want to send searched keyword in this format
`search/q/{{keyword}}/`

my html code is this

```
<form action="{% url 'content.search' q=searched_key %}" class="search-input">
    <input type="text" name="searched_key">
    <button type="submit"><i data-feather="search"></i></button>
</form>
```

i want to get input value and send but result url is this
http://127.0.0.1:8000/contents/search/q//?searched_key=test
how can i do it in right way?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using javascript to accomplish this.

```
<form id="form-id">
    <input type="text" id="searched_key" name="searched_key">
    <button type="submit"><i data-feather="search"></i></button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function submitForm(e) {
    // Prevent default form submit
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the search query
    let query = document.getElementById("searched_key").value;
    // redirect to the url with the query appended
    window.location.href = "/contents/search/" + query + "/";
    return false;
}

// Add an event listener to the form when the page loads
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("form-id").addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
});

</script>
```

Comment: What wasn't working? I may have misunderstood the original question

Comment: django raise an error with this message arguments not found.
i hardcoded the url and added return false at the end of the function.
it worked.
thankyou for your help

Comment: Awesome, I just noticed I made a typo in the `{% url %}`, I used an underscore by mistake, that is probably where the arguments not found came from. (I've updated my answer)

Comment: no i correct that before test. it is because in the view we had a format that gets argument. like: 
q=searched_key
and the format was like
/contents/search/{q}/
i tried this ```var url = "/contents/search/" + input + "/"```
and used ```window.location.href = url```
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can `POST` your search value as form (don't need to use `/search/q//?searched_key=test` in url) and your view should be something like this:

```
def search_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_key = form.save()
        search_result = Content.objects.filter(key=search_key)

    context = {
        'results': search_result,
    }
    return render(request, 'content.html', context)
```